# Second call to javascript click() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem when calling this function:

```
function dobleevent(obj){
    if (document.total.motivo.value){
       document.total.resumen.click();
       document.total["modificar"][0].click();      
    } else{
       alert("TextArea Empty");
       return false;
    }
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<input class="boton1" name="modificar"
  type="button" id="modificar" value="Modificar"
  onclick="dobleevent(this);">
```

The problem is that it only executes the first `click` method and it does not executes the next one. Why?

Comment: provide html code..have to check error in firebug?

Comment: What error is shown in a browser debugger ? what is `document.total` ?

Comment: What is `document.total["modificar"][0]`?

Comment: total is the name of the form.

and document.total["modificar"][0] it executes the button

Comment: well if I use document.total["modificar"][0].click(); inside the onclick event, it works fine by triggering the button that i want. But before that i need to trigger another button that actually validates the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really advise you to use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). That way you can make a difference between HTML and JavaScript.

Maybe using a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

So it would be:

HTML:

```
<input class="boton1" name="modificar" type="button" id="modificar" value="Modificar" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#modificar').on('click', function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: im just wondering why is not executing the second method:

document.total["modificar"][0].click();

If they are both one after another, it only executes the first one, but both methods work perfectly when they arent together